# Sharepoint 2013 Survey error with permissions

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, survey

I have a survey on a SharePoint 2013 server that has a "Visitors" group for permissions. This group has contribute access and contains all NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users. The goal is anyone on our system can access this survey. I was able to set the options to only allow the survey to be taken once and after submitting the user is redirected to a "Thank you" page. Issue I am having is most of the users tested this with (I can access fine but I am a admin) can complete the survey but get a error "Access denied" when they attempt to submit and it doesn't save any of their results. Is there a issue using NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users?

Comment: I recommend you to check if the "Survey List" has exclusive permissions. And try to replace NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users to "All".

Comment: Visitors groups is normally read only, check the permissions of the survey list first and make sure that they have permission

Comment: I am only a local site collections admin, so I don't have permissions to change NT Authority to All. When I attempt it I get a error "Everyone, all users, and domain user tokens are not allowed. Please delete them."

I specifically set this visitors group permission on this survey as contribute but the page it sits on is read only to the group. 

I checked the permissions on one of the people who has been able to access the survey and he has identical permissions with someone who doesn't.